# Cucumber - Capybara - Jquery -Dropdown value does not call OnChange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I am writing the test cases using capybara (2.4.4) ,cucumber (1.3.19),cucumber-rails (1.4.2) for the rails 4 application . 
The application has a drop down box which **onchange** calls the jquery function. I had put a debug statement

```
save_and_open_screenshot
```

which shows that the text in the select box is selected but it did not fire the onchange event

```
$("#engagement_list").on("change", function () {}
```

After selecting the text in the drop-down I had put

```
find('#engagement_list').native.send_keys(:return)
```

But it  did not invoke the onchange function.  In my cucumber feature file i am using **@javascript** tag.Do you know what may be wrong ?

Comment: What version of poltergeist are you using?  Also Capybara 2.4.4 is pretty old now, you may want to update to a newer version.  How are you selecting the text in the dropdown? Another thing to try is clicking in a different element on the page and see if that triggers the change event

Comment: I tried selecting other elements on the page it did not trigger the change event. 
One thing I noticed is that , we are running the test cases on the mocks where its not triggering the change event.
I tried running the similar cucumber -capybara  tests on the application deployed in server. It worked. 
Dont know what went wrong with the mocked version of code.

Answer (score 2):

Trough capybara you can trigger the **change** event like here:

```
select my_value, from: "My select Label" # select in order after submitting a form to send it to my server
page.execute_script("$('#engagement_list').trigger('change')")
```

[Capybara prof](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#scripting)

Answer (score 0):

Try properly selecting the option.  Assuming option[0] is a "Select One" message, here is some RSpec:

```
def select_third_option(id)
  third_option_xpath = "//*[@id='#{id}']/option[3]"
  third_option = find(:xpath, third_option_xpath).text
  select(third_option, :from => id)
end
```

Select should trigger the [onchange](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0102/0102-ONCHANGE-SELECT.html) event.

Comment: If you've already found the option element you can just call #select_option on it - so in your example  `find(:xpath, third_option_xpath).select_option`  - there is no need to go back and call `#select` which will just do another find in your document, waste time, and end up calling select_option anyway

Comment: I am selecting the option by 
page.select '8832483 | Goofy App 1 | IMAP-12341', :from => 'engagement_list'